# PHP v5.3.3 vss SSL/TLS certificate URL

Tags: php, apache, ssl

I cant load ssl/tls certificate URL from putty. Linux server PHP version 5.3.3 (xampp). I get below error ..

[root@l certs]# **/opt/lampp/bin/curl -v**  https://services.t.com:9773/cApps/services/CBLWebServices?wsdl

- About to connect() to services.t.com port 9773 (#0)
- Trying 172.17.171.11... connected
- Connected to services.l.com (172.17.171.11) port 9773 (#0)
- successfully set certificate verify locations:11
- CAfile: /opt/lampp/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
- SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
- Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to services.l.com:9773
- Closing connection #0

curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to services.l.com:9773

Comment: Although you have PHP installed, you are just trying this with the command line curl, is this something that is also happening in PHP?

Comment: a google search showed a blog of a few cases and ways to further debug it: https://blog.techstacks.com/2010/03/3-common-causes-of-unknown-ssl-protocol-errors-with-curl.html

Comment: php:  file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto